# Javascript Call Api "POST | PUT /events/..."

Tags: javascript, html, api, rest, post

I'm working to integrate some api into my website. I'd like to call it through javascript. The api documentation looks like this

```
POST | PUT /events/ws/api/... ["..." for security reasons]
```

How would I call something like this in Javascript? I think that it is a POST call, but how do I format a call for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object to make the call.

> `XMLHttpRequest` is a JavaScript object that was designed by Microsoft and adopted by Mozilla, Apple, and Google. It's now being standardized in the W3C. It provides an easy way to retrieve data at a URL. Despite its name, XMLHttpRequest can be used to retrieve any type of data, not just XML, and it supports protocols other than HTTP (including file and ftp).

However, if you can use the jQuery JavaScript library, it wraps the usage of this object and makes it a lot easier to work with, using the jQuery [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) functions.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/events/ws/api/",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```